# Why am I encountering R fatal error when running scripts from RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I upgraded my R version from 4.0.2 to 4.0.5 within RStudio and since then I have been having this fatal error on R each time that I run a script in RStudio. I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and RStdio but the problem still persists.

Comment: *"this fatal error"* ... which fatal error? R has many many errors, we won't guess (and even if we did the chances of it being correct are low).

Comment: Welcome to SO, Chinedu! Questions on StackOverflow are strongly recommended to be as reproducible as possible, to include *sample* (unambiguous) data (best from `dput(head(.))`), code attempted including non-base packages in use, and the expected output. When there are warnings or errors, those need to be included with the verbatim text. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and/or https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info, then come back and [edit] your question to add content. Thanks!

Comment: It says R Session Aborted. R Encounted a fatal error. This session was terminated. Start a new session.

Comment: There are too many things to really know. Places to look (and temporarily remove): `~/.Rprofile` (homedir), `./.Rprofile` (current dir), `./.Rdata`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but, the error was caused by the use of the xlsx library, I had to uninstall it and everything worked normally.